# Is it better to use a JavaScript event or window function for two products to talk to each other?

Tags: javascript, function, events

If I'm integrating some JavaScript on a customer website, and I need them to let me know when something specific happens on their page, is it better to attach an event handler to the body or some other global element, and have them raise that event as necessary, or would it be better to simply define a global function (on the window object) that they can call/execute when needed?

Is one faster than the other?  Is there a best practice for this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can research this by seeing what sites like google analytics, mixpanel, kissmetrics do.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Are you going to run this code in response to some *event*? Use an event handler. Otherwise, use a function.

Answer (score 0):

By event do you mean a DOM event like "mouseover" ? If yes in your use case where you have end users that may want to write code to use your facility I imagine situations where they might do a typo and throw event "BoughtChese" instead of "BoughtCheese". In this case the event wouldn't be caught and they'd be scratching their head for a little while.

If you meant an event system such as jQuery events or YUI custom events then why not but this approach becomes useful if more than one object is interested in the event and/or if you need to process in a particular way (asynchronously or by putting into a queue).

I'd say simple global functions part of a global object, eg. dan.Notify("BoughtCheese") seems enough for you needs. If your end users miswrite the function they'll get a console error and if they miswrite the parameter name you could always add an error checking code to detect it. It would be better if your end users could use an agreed set of integers and not use strings to refer to events, eg. dan.Notify(BOUGHT_CHEESE); that way you'd get rid of typo errors and error checking would be faster (checking that an event integer id is beyond array range).

Unless you're doing heavy computation speed shouldn't be an issue, and anyway a function call should be faster.